# A2C not converge as the loss explode

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I'm experimenting with Advantage Actor Critic algorithm, and the loss explode **exponentially**.

like

| iteration | actor_loss | critic_loss |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | -0.072878 | 0.003239 |
| 78 | -256202.2 | 254041.0 |
| 428 | -1.02e+17 | 7.17e+16 |

The actor network and critic network share the same base network and have separate consequent layers.

I've checked that the predicted *value* is also exploding to (negative) the same order of magnitude as the losses.

The update session is like this:

```
    for log_prob, value, R in zip(log_prob_list, value_list, returns):
        advantage = R - value
        # actor loss
        policy = -log_prob * advantage
        policy_losses.append(policy.mean())

        # critic loss
        value_losses.append(F.smooth_l1_loss(value, R))

    loss1 = torch.stack(policy_losses).sum()
    loss2 = torch.stack(value_losses).sum()

    loss = loss1 + beta * loss2 - 0.001 * total_entropy
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

I'm wondering what's wrong, somehow I think the **explosion is reasonable** as the network outputs low *value* close to negative infinity which makes *advantage* close to positive infinity and policy_loss -> negative infinity.

I've tried increase beta to even 1e4 but this didn't help.

Can anyone correct/help me?